# Newer AP with older PoE injector

Tags: power-over-ethernet

I'm trying to power my newer AP (TP-LINK EAP225) through PoE using the injector that came with my older AP (TP-LINK TL-WA901ND)

The old AP does work when powered through PoE using the injector. The newer AP doesn't.

Do I need a different PoE injector for the new one? Why is it not compatible with the old injector?

[image: Top - New AP, Bottom - Old AP]

[image: The PoE injector for the old AP]

Comment: Which PoE standards do the injector and router adhere to?

Comment: The new AP is  IEEE802.3af PoE. The injector - I don't have the info for it (trying to find the specs of the AP but it shows newer versions of the device)

Comment: We will need that information to answer your question

Comment: I suppose its "passive PoE", the specs of the next hardware version of the old AP says it supports "Passive PoE" (https://cdn.cnetcontent.com/7a/4b/7a4bd360-b962-463b-9663-6b416a4bc9ee.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the look of it, the "PoE injector" is a passive "run power along network connection" type adapter. It most probably uses the otherwise unused wires in a Fast Ethernet connection to pass the PSU power to the device. This isn't PoE.

You can tell by looking at the "injector's" power supply: if it outputs 48 to 54 V it most probably is a real PoE injector and should work with any PoE device. If the PSU just outputs 9 or 12 V it's a passive adapter which you'd have to replace.

If you buy a new one you should note that not all PoE injectors are gigabit capable - in case you need that.

Comment: I've done some more research and it is as you say. I've ordered a 48V passive gigabit PoE injector which in my understanding should have an isolation transformer for the 2 pairs the power is sent through. Will see if it works. Active ones are quite expensive.